# Google chart does not draw graph in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, charts, safari, google-api, google-visualization

So Google chart work fine in all other browsers except Safari.
First of all Safari could not load the api by this code: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>` and i had to follow chart's load whith this code: `<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>`. This code work but im not shure what is this good solution. Is it good or not?

### Main trouble

After chart finally show itself in Safari he was just empty. All data what im put in it not displayed. My chart function (triggered on click):

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
function showChart(id,obj,dataname,datatype,start,end){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: path_to+"ajax.php",
        data: {  
            's': start,
            'e': end,
            'title': id,
            'p': datatype,
            'f': 'crt'
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            if(Object.keys(data).length){
                var chda = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                chda.addColumn('datetime', 'Время');
                chda.addColumn('number', dataname);
                for(i in data) chda.addRow([new Date(data[i]['date']+' '+data[i]['datetime']),parseInt(data[i][datatype])]);

                var options = {
                    title: obj+': '+dataname,
                    vAxis: {minValue: 0},
                    backgroundColor: '#123',
                    areaOpacity: 0.5,
                    theme: 'maximized',
                    hAxis: {
                        viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
                        title: '',  
                        titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'},
                        gridlines: {
                            count: -1,
                            units: {
                                days: {format: ['MMM dd']},
                                hours: {format: ['HH:mm', 'ha']},
                            }
                        },
                        minorGridlines: {
                            units: {
                                hours: {format: ['HH:mm', 'ha']},
                                minutes: {format: ['HH:mm a Z', ':mm']}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(chda, options);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

There no errors in console and data is really exist (tested through alerts) but Safari not put data in the chart. How can i track and fix this problem?
And sorry for my english, its not my home language.

Comment: @WhiteHat data is an object and `chda.getNumberOfRows()` return "57".

Comment: @WhiteHat i had tried to remove all options and this not help me. Chart still stand empty. I think the problem is what Safari doesn't pass `chda` object or corrupt this. Maybe its problem whith specific chart's loading for Safari? I forced to use this code for chart's loading: `<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>` and it can may some troubles whith version or something else?

Comment: @WhiteHat im not use callback becouse i need show chart after click on button but not on initialization. Also chart booting outside function, in init code section and before function triggered becouse user just can't click on trigger button before init code completed. And only `loader.js` not work by itself but only whith `jsapi?autoload` in Safari. In all other browsers `loader.js` is enough.

Answer (score 4):

On safari javascript Date class does not support "yyyy-mm-dd H:M:S" format. You have to remove "H:M:S" when you are passing it in Date class. Instead you can append "H:M:S" in the date string after getting the date from the Date class.

Answer (score 0):

Im finally solve my problem. Google chart work in Safari whith 1.30 version of jsapi library. It mean you need to put this booting code: `<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.30','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>`.
It make some different, for example whith 1.30 version chart load like iframe and this can make some another problems.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Google uses the User Agent with which to condemn browsers as being incapable of displaying (SVG) charts, instead of feature detection!

This is yet another malicious tactic intended to squeeze competing browsers out of the market.

See related bug/issue report here…

https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2209

In retaliation to such unethical tactics, I strongly suggest nobody uses Google’s charts.